# Why is $scope.someArray.push not a valid function to pass to .then on $q.promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Relevant fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/tqf4zea7/1/

I'm using $q in an angular controller.  To test some scenarios, I created an array on the scope to push messages to:

```
$scope.messages = [];
```

I have set up a function that returns a $q function as so:

```
function returnAPromise(valToReturn){
    return $q(function(resolve, reject){
        $timeout(function(){
            resolve(valToReturn);
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

I then have a `.then()` call on the result that looks like this:

```
returnAPromise('third').then($scope.messages.push);
```

Since I only want to push the value that the promise was resolved with to the array, I figured I could just pass in the push method of the messages array, but when I do that, I get the following error:

```
VM289 angular.js:12520 TypeError: Array.prototype.push called on null or undefined
    at processQueue (VM289 angular.js:14792)
    at VM289 angular.js:14808
    at Scope.$eval (VM289 angular.js:16052)
    at Scope.$digest (VM289 angular.js:15870)
    at Scope.$apply (VM289 angular.js:16160)
    at VM289 angular.js:17927
    at completeOutstandingRequest (VM289 angular.js:5552)
    at VM289 angular.js:5829
```

If I enclose push in a function, it works fine:

```
returnAPromise('third').then(function(message){ 
     $scope.messages.push(message) 
});
```

Is this a closure issue I don't understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to bind push since it uses `this`

```
returnAPromise('third').then($scope.messages.push.bind($scope.messages));
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind Examples section describes the issue and why .bind() resolves it.  Unfortunately, it includes the line "A common mistake for new JavaScript programmers".  =[  I've been demoted.

Answer (score 1):

I know there is an accepted answer, but i will explain this more clearly here

## Example

lets start with an example

```
var scope = {
  scopeFn: function() {
    console.log('this', this)
  }
}

function callFn(fn) {
  fn();
}

callFn(obj.scopeFn) // will log window object 
callFn(function() {
  obj.scopeFn();
});// will log scope object
```

as you can see, wrapping the function will give the called object the value of this, but calling it directly without wrapping it will call the window object.

## why?

`this` will bind to the object its called from.

In the first example `callFn(obj.scopeFn)` you are passing the function as a parameter, hence when the function is called, its called directly not from the `scope` object. (`scope` object is lost, only the function reference is sent).

in the second example you are calling the function `scopeFn` from the object, hence the `this` will bind to its object. (`scope` object is not lost, as the whole thing is there when its called)

## Solution

To solve this issue you need to bind the function you are passing as a parameter for the resolve, so it will always be called as if it is called from its parent object.

```
var scopeMessage = $scope.messages;
returnAPromise('third').then(scopeMessage.push.bind(scopeMessage));
```